# populate select from input with angularJs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to create my custom directive data-from .

data-from="id-employee"

the attribute "data-from" indicates that the inputs of this fieldset must contains the values of the fieldsets which id start with "id-employee"

the user should be able to select a leader from the list of the employee.

Any ideas??
Thanks in advance !!

```
<form>

    <fieldset id="id-employee[0]">
      <input type="text" name="name-employee[0]"/>
      <input type="text" name="lastname-employee[0]"/>
    </fieldset>

     <fieldset id="id-employee[1]">
      <input type="text" name="name-employee[1]"/>
      <input type="text" name="lastname-employee[1]"/>

    </fieldset> <fieldset id="id-employee[2]">
      <input type="text" name="name-employee[2]"/>
      <input type="text" name="lastname-employee[2]"/>
    </fieldset>


   <fieldset id="id-leader" data-from="id-eployee">
  <select id="select-employee">
    <option>Select a Team leader</option>
    <option id="select-employee-0" value="0">name lastname of the employee 0</option>
   <option id="select-employee-0" value="1">name lastname of the employee 1</option>
<option id="select-employee-0" value="2">name lastname of the employee 2</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="name-leader"/>
  <input type="text" name="lastname-leader"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data binding to achieve this like -

```
<form ng-init="employees=[]">
<fieldset id="id-employee[0]">
      <input type="text" model="employees[0].name" name="name-employee[0]"/>
      <input type="text" model="employees[0].lastname" name="lastname-employee[0]"/>
</fieldset>
```

and then bind it in select

```
<select ng-model="leader" ng-options="employee.name as employee.name for employee in employees"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I want to use a custom directive